# CannotGetJdbcConnectionException after upgrading springboot version

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, spring-jdbc

After upgrading `spring-boot-starter-parent` version to `2.6.14`, I'am getting following error, the code is working fine on my locale but after deploying on JBOSS server, I 'am getting exception : `Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver from ClassLoader:ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.xyz.war"`

```
     org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver from ClassLoader:ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.xyz.war" from Service Module Loader;ClassLoader:ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.xyz.war" from Service Module Loader
2023-05-08 06:17:46,741 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:83) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
2023-05-08 06:17:46,741 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:646) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
2023-05-08 06:17:46,742 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
2023-05-08 06:17:46,742 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
2023-05-08 06:17:46,742 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
```

java version : `1.8.0_222`
BJOSS version : `7.2`
spring jdbc : `spring-jdbc-5.3.24`

Comment: Check that the JAR file containing the Oracle JDBC driver is on the **runtime** classpath.

Comment: You probably should also consult this: https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/configuring-the-oracle-jdbc-drivers-in-a-springboot-project-take-2.  Note the dependencies from "com.oracle.database.jdbc" in the example POM file.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't easy to guess what's been changed, I'd suggest using the following strategy in such situations:

1. Find out a library that provides ojdbc module
2. Compare results of: mvn dependency:tree command after migration to a newer version and before the migration.
3. add a missing library to your pom or to your server libs directly

p.s. you may use maven helper plugin for more easy dependency:tree investigations